# Proof that this quadrilateral is a parallelogram is impossible.

Tags: problem-solving, quadrilateral

I found a problem and I think there is a mistake in it because nor just I can't figure out the solution but I also proved by just drawing the figure that the conclusion is wrong. I may also be wrong. Here is the problem:

Ipothesis: Let $ABCD$ a parallelogram and the points $A_1, B_1, C_1$ and $D_1$ in the parallelogram's plan. $M, N, P, Q \in AA_1, BB_1, CC_1, DD_1$ respectively so that $$\frac {MA}{MA_1} = \frac {NB}{NB_1}= \frac {PC}{PC_1} = \frac {QD}{QD_1} = k, k \in \mathbb R \backslash \{1\}$$
Conclusion: If $MNPQ$ is a quadrilateral then $MNPQ$ is parallelogram.

The conclusion sounds strange to me because $MNPQ$ is always a quadrilateral. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.
You can have a look at 
[the starter tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) 
to familiarize yourself further with the format.

Comment: Will $MNPQ$ be a quadrilateral,
if, say, points $M,N,P$ are on the same line?

Comment: @g.kov, I haven't tought of this. Thank you. However, even when they aren't on a line and $MNPQ$ is a quadrilateral, it still isn't always a paralelogram. I have a drawing but I don't have enough reputation to post it.

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample with random points $A_1,B_1,C_1,D_1$
inside the parallelogram $A,B,C,D$:

[image]

points $M,N,P,Q$ forms a quadrilateral, but it is not a parallelogram.

Hence, the hypothesis is false.